# Making a triangle using variable width output

Tags: python

I have to make a pyramid of asterisks like this:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
```

I have to use something called variable width output:

```
for count in range(1,60,3):
    myWidth = count
    myCharacter = '*'
    print('{0:>{width}}'.format(myCharacter, width=myWidth)).
```

I'm trying to find a way to loop that so it makes a pyramid, but with little results. What can I do?

Comment: what are you given? The height of the pyramid, the width of the base, the number of 'bricks'?

Comment: It's literally all up to us. We do have a variable 'myWidth', which'll give us the ultimate width of the triangle.

Comment: use `'*' * count`. And you need `2` in `range(1,60,2)`

Answer (score 0):

Below one should work for you.

```
def asterisks_printer(num):
    counter = 1
    while counter <= num:
        print '{:^{width}}'.format('*' * counter, width = num)
        counter +=2

asterisks_printer(5)
```

Output:

```
  *
 ***
*****
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use always the same `width` and then you can use `^` to center text - as shown Ahsanul Haque.

You need `2` (not `3`) in `range(1, width+1, 2)`

```
def display(width):
    for count in range(1, width+1, 2):
        print('{0:^{width}}'.format('*' * count, width=width))

display(7)
```

Or you have to use `(width+count)//2` to use `>`

```
def display(width):
    for count in range(1, width+1, 2):
        print('{0:>{width}}'.format('*'*count, width=(width+count)//2))

display(7)
```